# Form Won't Load After User LogIn

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a db with user login and previleges atributed to diferente type of users. And I also created a bypass property to enable or disable the "shift click" opening of the db. So, when a user of the type 4 logs in, a prompt appears to activate or deactivate theses propersties, and after a yes or, the user is presented with the inicial menu form. The is, when a user that isn't a level 4 user tries to log in, the login button doesn't react at all. The prompt of the bypass does not show up, has it is supposed to, but the menu form also won't open. Something is probably missing, but i just can't figure out, what. Can anyone help me?

```
Private Sub btnlogin()
Dim rs As Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblutilizadores", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

rs.FindFirst "[User ID]='" & Me.txtutilizador & "'"

If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    MsgBox "Utilizador Inválido", vbInformation, "Atenção!"
    Me.txtutilizador.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If rs!Password <> Me.txtpassword Then
    MsgBox "Password Inválida", vbInformation, "Atenção!"
    Me.txtpassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
End If

If IsNull(Me.txtpassword.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Introduza Password", vbInformation, "Atenção!"
    Exit Sub
End If

    TempVars("TipoUtilizador") = rs![Tipo ID].Value

If rs![Tipo ID] = 4 Then
    Dim prop As Property
On Error GoTo SetProperty
Set prop = CurrentDb.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False)

CurrentDb.Properties.Append prop

SetProperty:
If MsgBox("Ativar Bypass?", vbYesNo, "Bypass") = vbYes Then
    CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = True
    
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
Else
    CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = False
    
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
End If

End If

End Sub
```

Thank you all in advance.
Be safe.

Comment: Hello Alex, if you have the solution you could kindly check an anwser, indicating that the question is solved.

Comment: Hello @jacouh! :) Thank you so much for the heads up. I'm still new around here. Marked the solution and cheked the question as aswered. :)

Comment: @jacouh, just one more thing. I just applied this piece of code in one of the two front end i have distributed. And when trying to run it, I get a "Compile Error: User defined type, not defined." And on debug, it highlights the following: `PrivateSubCommand8_Click()`
`Dim rs As Recordset` Any idea of what might be missing? Because I don´t understand why it works on of the front ends, but no on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open menu for all types of users. You could try this code:

```
Private Sub btnlogin()
Dim rs As Recordset

  Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tblutilizadores", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)

  rs.FindFirst "[User ID]='" & Me.txtutilizador & "'"

  If rs.NoMatch = True Then
    MsgBox "Utilizador Inválido", vbInformation, "Atenção!"
    Me.txtutilizador.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If rs!Password <> Me.txtpassword Then
    MsgBox "Password Inválida", vbInformation, "Atenção!"
    Me.txtpassword.SetFocus
    Exit Sub
  End If

  If IsNull(Me.txtpassword.Value) Then
    MsgBox "Introduza Password", vbInformation, "Atenção!"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  TempVars("TipoUtilizador") = rs![Tipo ID].Value

  If rs![Tipo ID] = 4 Then
    Dim prop As Property
    On Error GoTo SetProperty
    Set prop = CurrentDb.CreateProperty("AllowBypassKey", dbBoolean, False)

    CurrentDb.Properties.Append prop

SetProperty:
    If MsgBox("Ativar Bypass?", vbYesNo, "Bypass") = vbYes Then
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = True
    
        'DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu"
        'DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    Else
        CurrentDb.Properties("AllowBypassKey") = False
    
        'DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu"
        'DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    End If

  End If

'
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing

'
' do this for all types of users:
'
  DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu"

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome @jacouh ! It worked! Thank you so much for your help. :)

Comment: With pleasure and glad to see you on so.